# How to dynamically add elements to a web page in the middle of a table

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an administrative webpage that has a customer search feature. I type the name and a table of matching customers (and a limited amount of pertinent data for each) is injected on to the page using ajax. I would like to be able to click on a customer (a row) and have the customer's profile show up. The profile may include multiple elements, forms, buttons, and complex functions.

Instead of having this profile be on a separate page or something, I would like it to be injected right in the spot that i clicked (below the customer's row), and then close back up when I'm done with it.

I have tried adding these elements to the DOM, but anything between the  tags comes in as part of the table (all squished into one cell). Should I split the table somehow first? or not use a table in the first place?

I'm looking for a robust solution because I will need to "insert modules" like this in other parts of the site as well.

Comment: two ways: one to make invisible row after each row, and two - dynamically add new rows and place user inf there.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want the data to appear inline (pushing other content down)**
I would add a second `<tr>` after the one with your customer (or replace it) with a single 
`<td>` whose `colspan` is set to fill the width of your table. You can then remove or `display:none` this row when it is no longer needed.

**If you want the data to appear overlaid (covering up other content)**
I would use JavaScript to determine the screen coordinates of the first TD in your row and position an absolutely-positioned div overlaid at that location. (This would be similar to a rich-content "tooltip".)

I would personally use the first if the user can reasonably be expected to want to compare data in the 'profile' to data already on screen for other customers. I would use the second solution if that is not the case, to minimize how much the content on the page changes (so that the user stays oriented).

Comment: the first solution sounds better. I wont lose orientation because everything above this customer stays still. the fact is, however the customer profile includes a lot... almost enough where it could be its own page. for instance it will have a few tables itself. Would this still work, putting multiple tables within a table?

Comment: I prefer option 2 (overlay or tooltip) because of the amount of space needed. Also, inserting additional rows could be an issue as the table has events (clicks) associated with each row.

Comment: @VoltzRoad Yes, you can nest arbitrary content inside a table cell, including ([if truly appropriate](http://phrogz.net/css/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html)) other tables.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar implementation last year.

Contrary to what others have suggested, I don't think adding rows is a good idea. The reason is that you'll want to use [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) to handle user clicks, and adding rows will mess up or at least complicate your implementation.

My choice was to insert a table within the existing customer row. An overlay or a tooltip would offer a cleaner implementation, but will only work if you need to expand only one customer at a time.